# .how to write single quote( ' ) in write predicate in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, quote

I want to add short info in the beginning of the program and i goes like this

```
message :-
    nl,nl,
    write('  To start type  '), nl,
    write(' ?- solve(Input1,Input2,Output3) '), nl.
:- message.
```

And this is fine...but i need   write(' ?-  solve('Input1','Input2',Output3) '), nl
so when i run the program it should print
To start type
?- solve(**'** Input1 **'** ,**'** Input2 **'** ,Output3 )

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What exactly should it display? Please use four leading spaces to format code snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the quote with **backslash**.

For example, to output a *single* single-quote:

```
?- write('\'').
'
true.
```

As a general rule, you should of course **avoid side-effects** *entirely*. A good solution is to *describe* the output using a DCG. This makes it amenable to **test cases**, which are hard to write if output only appears on the terminal.

`write/1` is particularly rarely used. If you really need to output something, use **`format/2`**. This sounds scary if you know DOS, but it really isn't.

An important advantage of `format/2` is that it lets you conveniently mesh static text with flexible arguments, for example:

```
?- member(X, [friend,foe,love]),
   format("hello my '~q'!\n", [X]),
   false.
```

Yielding:

```
hello my 'friend'!
hello my 'foe'!
hello my 'love'!
```

Note that the issue of single quotes didn't even arise in this case. The analogous issue with `"` can again be solved by using `\`:

```
?- format("a \"test\"", []).
a "test"
```